# MYSQL counting matches across multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4 ....
1   x3      y2      v7      i7  
2   x8      u4      r1      o2
3   m7      w2      x3      l1
4   j5      y2      t2      a5
5   u7      y2      v7      a5
6   b7      y2      x3      a5
```

I want to have a perfect match to col2, and order the results by highest number of matched across defined numbers of columns

For example, the query is col1=u7, col2=y2, col3=v7, the return results should be

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4 ....
5   u7      y2      v7      a5  (3 matches)
1   x3      y2      v7      i7  (2 matches)
4   j5      y2      t2      a5  (1 match)
6   b7      y2      x3      a5  (1 match)
```

So far, I have

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2 = 'y2' ORDER BY...
```

I wasn't sure what to put in the ORDER BY clause

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1):

You have to evaluate the matches one by one. I would use the `if()` functiona for that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2 = 'y2'
ORDER BY if(col1='u7',1,0) + if(col3='v7',1,0) + ... desc
```